# WCF Changing credentials

Tags: wcf, impersonation, credentials, basichttpbinding

I have a web app that calls a WCF web application with several services, all using basicHttBinding, on different servers (web server, app server and database server). One of the services has to connect to a database that must be called using an active directory account. Coming in from the web site the user is anonymous.

I have been given credentials to set this user to but I cannot get it to work. I create my channel on the web server like this:

```
ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = GetChannelFactoryFromPool<T>(enpointAddress);       
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

In the service on the app server I am trying to determine if the credentials are correct by doing this:

```
var ssc = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
```

but ssc is always null. Can this be done with basicHttpBinding?

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 2):

The basicHttpBinding does support Windows authentication as [documented in this good MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) You also need to ensure the service operations are configured to [allow impersonation of the client credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to have the security context populated as expected.